# Integrate jsdoc into docsify

Tags: node.js, vue.js, documentation, jsdoc3, docsify

Im trying to document my node.js/javascript application.
The frontend is a vue app & backend a node.js app.

I use jsdoc to document classes/modules etc. and need a way to integrate that into docsify.
At first i wanted to document the whole application in jsdoc, but it does not suits my needs.

Then i found docsify which let me more structure the layout and content for my whole application.

To not maintain two documentations i need a way to integrate the jsdoc annotated source code into docsify.

Is there a way to seamless integrate both tools? Has any one experience with this?

Any help/hint is welcomed. Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT:**

I didnt find a answer. What i now do is to create from the comments via the node.js package `parse-comments` a dataset for a custom template, which i then include into docisfy.

For anyone interested: https://github.com/OpenHausIO/documentation

Keeping this question open, perhaps some one has the same problem or even a solution to my initial question.